# Selenium : New tab is not getting opened on same browser in Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open a new tab in same browser but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and Selenium 3.0.0.

I used the below code:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "\t");`

Comment: have u searched the chrome settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using JavascriptExecutor as below:

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com');");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Robot class with Selenium Webdriver to open a new tab. We need to follow the below three steps-

1. Simulate pressing of Ctrl+t keys of keyboard using Robot class.
2. Switch to the new tab in selenium using driver.switchTo() command.
3. Open the desired link on new tab.

Code snippet-

```
//Launch the first URL
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

//Use robot class to press Ctrl+t keys          
Robot robot = new Robot();                          
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);

//Switch focus to new tab
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

//Launch URL in the new tab
driver.get("http://google.com");
```

Source: Code snippet from [Open a new tab in Selenium - ArtOfTesting](http://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/open-a-new-tab-in-selenium-webdriver-java.html)